# i m not able to fix my auto id generator

Tags: vb.net

I am able to successfully generate an id on form load but when I leave that form and try to load it again the  id generated is the same as the previous one

```
Try
        Dim num As Integer
        conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=rishab")
        conn.Open()
        sqlcommand = New MySqlCommand("select max(ID) from inc", conn)
        sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If IsDBNull(sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar) Then
            num = 1
            id5.Text = num
        Else
            num = sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar + 1
            id5.Text = num
        End If
        sqlcommand.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    autogenerate()

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you have a question for us?

Comment: what is the return type of your function autogenerate

Comment: Are you inserting anything into the table to increment the ID?

Comment: Why do you not just let the database do this for you?  It is generally a bad idea to try to 'roll your own' autogenerated id.

Comment: This is a bad idea and there is nothing "auto" about it, if you have code to create it.  MySQL is quite capable of generating unique Ids for you - thats part of its job.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand this correctly you need to declare your num Integer as public. It will then hold the latest value and when you re-load the form it will count on from the latest value. Do this before your form class starts or I will personally add this in a module with all my other public strings, booleans and integers.

```
''In a module add -
Public num As Integer 
''Do not add a value here as in Public num as Integer = 0 as it will give the value 0 every time you make a call to it.
''Also remember to handle the value throughout your app, change back to 0 or leave it to the last value etc.
```